# How to create button event occurs without page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net application where I have button written like this:-

```
<button onclick='javascript:imagech(this);' class='close_product color_dark tr_hover'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>
```

I have also a client-side javascript function for the above button:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function imagech() {
    alert('image clicked.');
  }
</script>
```

What I want that is whenever I click that function then the button click event should not fire page-load. The above object is not server control but it's event occurs page-load. I can also use another html control like this:

```
<input type='button' onclick='javascript:cartclicked(this);' value='X' class='close_product color_dark tr_hover' />
```

and this does not occurs page-load but I want icon also used as :

```
<i class='fa fa-times'></i>
```

inside `<button>` tag. but the `<i>` tag is not used in `<input>` tag. How I can `<button>` tag event without any page-load? Please help me someone here.

Comment: `without any page-load` i am not sure if i understand this one correctly

Comment: Use `JavaScript event binding` inside `window.onload` handler

Comment: @Rayon Dabre how can i use that?

Comment: `window.onload= function(){ document.getElementById(YOUR_ID).addEventListener('click', ....) }`

Comment: @guradio when i use <button> tag which is a html control not a server control and when i click on this the page-load occurs which i want to stop.

Comment: @Rayon Dabre but the button is inside master page and inside Listview then there might be several button with different id then how i can i write that function.

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('button.close_product')` and a loop to attach event to all the matched elements..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you are using `<button>` inside a `<form>` element. By default a button acts as a **submit** button and it **tries to submit your form on click**.

In order to continue using button and avoid this issue you need to specify **type** as button as shown below

```
<button type="button" onclick='javascript:imagech(this);' class='close_product color_dark tr_hover'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly the problem is that the button is inside a `form` (The main asp.net form) and the `click` event post the form to the server. That's why you the page load occurred.

**The solution** Just add to the button (it doesn't matter if you are using `input` or `button`) attribute `type="button"`.